# C# An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, exception, unhandled

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I have a program that asks for an input, 1 of 2 options, and then displays the cost of the associated option.

I am getting the error message "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: String must be exactly one character long."

What have I done wrong with my code? See below:

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace computerPackage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char computerPackage;
            const decimal DELUXE_PACKAGE = 1500;
            const decimal SUPER_PACKAGE = 1700;
            Console.Write("Input the Computer Package D or S: ");
            computerPackage = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            computerPackage = Char.ToUpper(computerPackage);
            if (computerPackage == 'D')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cost of Deluxe Computer Package is " + DELUXE_PACKAGE.ToString("D"));
            }
            else if (computerPackage == 'S')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cost of Deluxe Computer Package is " +
                SUPER_PACKAGE.ToString("S"));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Package D or S not entered");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();          // pause
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to check your input (Console.Readline() ) for exactly one character first. Seems your char.Parse-method is getting too much input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro the reason why errors is `Console.WriteLine("Cost of Deluxe Computer Package is " + DELUXE_PACKAGE.ToString(D));`is telling the runtime environment to set it to datetime format. change it to `Console.WriteLine("Cost of Deluxe Computer Package is " + DELUXE_PACKAGE.ToString());`

Comment: no probs. Just remember to keep .tostring() parameter empty as in most cases it always empty. Only in needed time.

Comment: Great, thank you. This may come in handy for another problem I'm having with something else!

Comment: Hey mate, actually one more question - I still get an error if I have no input entered, I want it to return Console.WriteLine("Package D or S not entered"); but instead I get the same error message as in my question - what do I need to fix there?

Comment: the problem is that readline, if left empty, takes a series of whitespaces, wheres only read takes a single character.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your ToString methods on the decimals. There are specific formats you can request, take a look at them here:

[ToString(Format)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks mate, a bit confused looking at it, I'm not entirely too sure what I should be changing it to

Comment: sorry, but this is just wrong, isnt it? the formatexception of tostring adds as "additional information", a.k.a. condition "format is invalid", which is not what the op got. ops problem is in char.parse(...).

Comment: @Dominik - any suggestions what I need to fix?

Comment: @LegendIsReal see my comment. can't say anything without the exact input atm ;)

Comment: As @Dominik said, one problem is char.parse, the other would be tostring. So, u can change computerPackage = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); to computerPackage = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper(); and use plain .ToString() on decimals to display them.